# Why end variables with hash symbol in macros?

Tags: variables, clojure, naming-conventions

I was looking `clojure.core`'s macro [implementation of `and`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/028af0e0b271aa558ea44780e5d951f4932c7842/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L801-L811) and I noticed that some of the `let` bindings in this source file's macros end their variable name with and octothorpe (`#`).

Upon further inspection with the following code...

```
(defn foo# [] 42)
(foo#) ; => 42
```

...I realized that octothorpe is just a valid symbol (at least when included on the end).

So, my question is, why do these core macros end their binding symbols with a hash character? Is there some specific implied meaning or convention I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The # at the end of a symbol is interpreted specially by the reader as a shortcut for [gensym](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/gensym).

```
(gensym "foo")
;=> foo3

(defmacro hygienic []
  `(let [foo# 42] foo#))

(hygienic)
;=> 42

(macroexpand '(hygienic))
;=> (let* [foo__1__auto__ 42] foo__1__auto__)
```

Comment: Ah, so it does this to ensure there isn't binding shadowing in recursive calls?

Comment: @mjgpy3 right, to not shadow other vars, you can read about macros - http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/

Comment: `gensym` is mainly used within macros to ensure hygiene, which is, exactly as you say, avoding accidentially shadowing existing variables in the environment of the macro at expansion time. Clojure docs has an explanation at http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/macros.html

Comment: Not just shadowing, but also symbol capture, which is sorta the opposite of shadowing: when your macro uses a symbol that it thinks it has bound, but has really been rebound by the user of the macro.

Comment: @mjgpy3 I've added examples of gensym (via the `gensym` function) and auto gensym (adding `#` onto the end of a symbol name within the context of a macro). I think it's easier to understand when you see it in practice.