# Clojure macro with try block error: cannot bind qualified name

Tags: clojure, macros

I am trying to define a macro which writes code to execute a try catch block for the expression that is passed in.

```
(defmacro safe
     [expression]
     `(try
          ~expression 
          (catch Exception e (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e)))
      )
)
```

The macro writes fine but when I run some tests on it, I receive the following compiler errors

```
seminar.core=> (def v (safe (/ 1 0)))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't bind qualified name:seminar.core/e, compiling:(/private/var/folders/6f/q7lhngtn45q_xpzd_24gjp2h0000gn/T/form-init2350735096437822603.clj:1:8) 

seminar.core=> (def v (safe (/ 10 2)))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't bind qualified name:seminar.core/e, compiling:(/private/var/folders/6f/q7lhngtn45q_xpzd_24gjp2h0000gn/T/form-init2350735096437822603.clj:1:8)
```

This is how the macro should behave

```
user> (def v (safe (/ 1 0)))
user> v
#<ArithmeticException java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero>
user> (def v (safe (/ 10 2)))
user> v
5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generate a unique symbol for `e` in your macro:

```
(defmacro safe
  [expression]
  `(try ~expression
     (catch Exception e#
       (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e#)))))
```

Then you get the desired behavior:

```
(safe (/ 1 0))
=> "caught exception: Divide by zero"
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25514411) related question. The `#` suffix is a special shorthand for [`gensym`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gensym). One reason this is necessary is so that bindings in your macro don't *overshadow* other bindings of the same name when the macro is expanded.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to extend the macro to take any number of expressions returning the last one as a positive result. My version is:

```
(defmacro safe [& body]
  `(try
     (do ~@body)
     (catch Exception e#
       (println (format "Error: %s" (.getMessage e#))))))
```

Usage example:

```
(safe
 (+ 1 2)
 (println "hey")
 (/ 42 0))
```

It evaluates all the forms before those one which causes an error. The result will be `nil` value with printing the error message in console:

```
hey
Error: Divide by zero
nil
```